# Create New topic in Fourms in bbpress WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, buddypress, bbpress

I want to create new topic using code/programmatically in bbpress WordPress.I searched but didn't find any related code.Can anyone help me by providing any kind of help related.Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try these functions :

```
 bbp_insert_topic(), bbp_insert_forum(), and bbp_stick_topic()
```

For details you can try like this :

```
$topic_data = apply_filters( 'bbp_new_topic_pre_insert', array(
        'post_author'    => $topic_author,
        'post_title'     => $topic_title,
        'post_content'   => $topic_content,
        'post_status'    => $topic_status,
        'post_parent'    => $forum_id,
        'post_type'      => bbp_get_topic_post_type(),
        'tax_input'      => $terms,
        'comment_status' => 'closed'
    ) );

    // Insert topic
    $topic_id = wp_insert_post( $topic_data );
```

You can also found this code in `plugin/bbpress/includes/funcion.php` page.Hope this can help you

Comment: Great thanks.I will check these in details.